# What is wrong with this Array

Tags: java, arrays

```
//Prime Number Calculator

import java.util.Scanner;

class PrimeNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int End;
        int Begin;  

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        //insert max value for the calculator.
        System.out.println("Where should I stop?");
        End = in.nextInt();

        for (Begin=3; Begin<=End; Begin++){
            System.out.println(Begin);
            int Prime;
            int PrimeList[] ;

            //something is wrong around here... I don't understand what...

            for (Prime:PrimeList); 
                PrimeList[0]=2;
            if(Begin%PrimeList[Prime]!=0){
                break;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

I know there are many prime number calculators out there, but for school I wanted to make one but I don't know where I went wrong.

error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on token "Prime", Identifier expected after this token
Prime cannot be resolved to a type
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type int to Prime

at PrimeNumbers.main(PrimeNumbers.java:25)
```

Comment: What do you want to do? What is `PrimeList`?

Comment: Define what you mean by "something is wrong": does it compile? If no, what error message does it give? Does it run? If not, what error message does it give? Does it produce what you want? If not, what *does* it produce and what do you *expect* it to produce.

Comment: What do you mean 'something is wrong'. If you get an error, post it. If you get a wrong result, post that. etc. help us help you

Comment: wrong way of naming variables.Your local variables should start with small letters.

Comment: i want to make it generate a list of primes, and put them in an array called PrimeList

Comment: every time you are declaring the array `int PrimeList[] ;` what exactly do you want to do?\

Comment: By convention all Java class members and variables start with lowercase. Because else you dont see the difference between a class and members/variables.

Comment: What do you expect `for (Prime:PrimeList);` to do?

Comment: so far, i'm not close to being done with the program but my class is about to end so thanks to anyone who is helping me!

Comment: @MeNoMore Your edit is incorrect grammatically ("Whats" should be "What is" or "What's"), and makes the code harder to read. Please do not roll back to your edit again.

Comment: @AndrewBarber your right, thank you, but why didnt you change it? it's still "whats". I'll change this to "What is".

Comment: @AndrewBarber you changed the variable names from the original post, which actually are not according to naming convention but still all answer are based on these names, this is'nt right unless you change all the rest in the answers, otherwise answers will be seen as leading to wrong practice and actually wrong, i hope we agree about this, i changed these and the formatting.

Comment: @Menomore *You* changed the variable names, and messed up the code formatting. All I did was rollback your erroneous edit.

Comment: @AndrewBarber thats along story, the time i changed the title i rolled back an older change, but if you see the history you will notice that the original post had these funny names with End and Beginn in capital letters, you can notice these in the exception output attached down the code and on the answers. About the formatting i just made it more like java formatting notning else.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so your code has got a couple of problems (Ok, may be more), which I'll list here:

**Problem 1:**

First thing first. Always follow Java Naming Conventions. Your variable names and method names should start with lowercase alphabets. So:

```
int End;   // Should be `int end;`
int Begin; // Should be `int begin;`
```

**Problem 2:**

You have just declared your array reference, and not initialized it. The below statement is just declaring an array reference of type int:

```
int PrimeList[] ;
```

You need to create an array object, and assign the reference to it:

```
int PrimeList[] = new int[size];
```

**Problem 3:**

This problem is an extension to the **problem 2**. Notice that, you are initializing a new array on each iteration of your loop. So, all your prime numbers would not be accumulated at the same place. Rather, your `array` will clear up after each iteration. You should remove that array declaration from inside the loop.

Now, rather than adding the *array declaration* outside the loop, I would suggest you to use an `ArrayList` instead, which is a dynamically increasing array. So, you won't have to give an initial size.

So, you can add the below declaration outside the *outer* `for` loop:

```
List<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

**Problem 4:**

Let's move ahead to your *inner* `for` loop:

```
for (Prime:PrimeList); 
    PrimeList[0]=2;
    if(Begin % PrimeList[Prime] != 0){
        break;
    }
}
```

For now, just forget what's wrong with that loop, because that loop is not needed at all. You haven't yet initialized your `list`. So, there is  no point in iterating over it. You rather need to initialize it with prime numbers between specified range.

So, rather than having a for loop to iterate the *array / list*, you should test the current number you are testing, whether it's prime or not. If it's prime, add it to the list. And to test a prime number, you would need a loop for each number. I suggest to move that logic in separate method. To check whether a number is prime or not, you keep on dividing it by numbers from `2` to `num / 2`. And as soon as you see that `modulus = 0`, `return false` else `return true`: -

```
public boolean isPrime(int num) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now, let's get back to your original method. And take a look at your outer loop:

```
for (begin=3; begin <= end; begin++) {
    /** For each number, check whether it's prime or not **/
    if (isPrime(begin)) {
        /** Is Prime, add it to list **/
        primeList.add(begin);
    }
}
```

This was it. Now, I suggest you to go through the answer step by step, and solve each problem individually.

Comment: This is why i voted the other answers down, because i was waiting for somebody give a decent answer without repeating mistakes like this one.

Answer (score 1):

In java, [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) are objects, and should be initialized using `new`.

```
int[] PrimeList = new int[10];
```

Comment: By convention all Java class members and variables start with lowercase. Because else you dont see the difference between a class and members/variables.

Comment: @Azodious.. Ok, may be this shouldn't be downvoted because of naming convention reason. But just think, will this sole change in the code make it work? There are plenty of problems in there. Your answer could have been better if you took care of all of them, or none of them.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by other you have not initialized your `PrimeList` array.

---

Other suggestions with respect to code.

1. You should do validations on the input you are taking. Check [Exception handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) for the same. For example, if the user didn't enter a number where you had expected one then your code will break.
2. The variable names are not in a java-bean specification format i.e. the first letter should be in small caps and then should follow the *camelCase* notation which is to capitaize first letter of each next word in the variable name.
3. The algo seems to be completely wrong. PrimeList is not being populated anywhere, unless you have generated them in a separate code and didn't integrate that in the above given code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your for loop. It should be

```
for (int prime: primeList) {
```

Short  for loops require the type of the variable used in the iteration

Answer (score -1):

You have to initate your Array, for example:

```
int PrimeList[] = new int[3]
```

Comment: By convention all Java class members and variables start with lowercase. Because else you dont see the difference between a class and members/variables.

Comment: Im sorry but i think we dont agree on this matter, check the answer that Rohit Jain gave and my comment to it.

Comment: I dont have fun downvoting, it irritates me when i see people repeat obvious mistakes. Mistakes that an experienced programmer should know in my opinion.

Comment: Yes i do expect that, and i expect a decent explanation for it, which you failed to give.

Comment: You are pathetic dude, going to downvote all my answers now because i downvoted yours? How old are you?

Answer (score -1):

I think You have not intialize both your variables `int Prime;` and `int PrimeList[];`

Initialize them as

```
int Prime = 0;
int PrimeList[] = new PrimeList[10];
```